# VBA: For Loop to find maximum value in a column

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

How would you go about finding the maximum value in a column using a for loop?

I want to be able to store the maximum value in a variable.

Comment: `ThisMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A:A"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the corresponding value in Column C where column A is max:

```
dim t as long
dim rslt as string
With Worksheets("RESOURCE") ' Change to your sheet
    t = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range("AX6:AX29")),.Range("AX6:AX29"),0)
    rslt = .Range("A6:A29")(t)
    Debug.Print rslt
End With
```

[image]

---

But this can be done with the following formula on the sheet:

```
=INDEX(RESOURCE!A6:A29,MATCH(MAX(RESOURCE!AX6:AX29),RESOURCE!AX6:AX29,0))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm working with two different workbooks, so I can't use the formula you provided. I am trying to find the maximum in column AX. For the Range ("AX6:AX29"). This is currently what I have but it's giving me the wrong value.                                                    
 Dim r As Long
    Dim t As Long
    Dim rslt As String
    With Worksheets("RESOURCE") ' Change to your sheet
        r = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range("AX6:AX29"))
        t = Application.Match(r, .Range("A6:A29"), 0)
        rslt = .Cells(t, "A")
        Debug.Print rslt
    End With

Comment: You need to Match the Max in the same range in which you found the max.  Se edit

Answer (score 0):

Scott Craner's answer is by far the best option.

If you are required to use a for loop, something like this...

Set the values of firstRow to be the row number containing the first line of data. columnNumber is the index of the column containing the items you are calculating the max of:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim firstRow As Integer
Dim columnNumber As Integer
Dim max As Integer

firstRow = 1
columnNumber = 6

Set sheet = ActiveSheet

If sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count <= 1 Then max = NaN Else max = sheet.Cells(firstRow, columnNumber)

For i = firstRow + 1 To sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If sheet.Cells(i, columnNumber) > max Then max = sheet.Cells(i, columnNumber)
Next

sheet.Cells(1, 1) = max
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to associate the maximum value with another value in the same row but a different column. That's why a for loop was the first idea that came into my mind.

Comment: @user7062450 then you should ask that question, use MATCH to return the row in which the max is found, then reference that row and the desired column to return the correct value.  You can also do that with a INDEX/MATCH formula on the worksheet and skip vba.